# SVG CSS | SVG only works in chrome

Tags: html, css, svg, cross-browser

Having issues with an SVG I have made.

It works great in chrome and does exactly what i want and expect it too but I cannot get it working in any other browser (tried IE and Firefox so far).

My SVG is an image with a clip path cutting it out into the shape I want and this works on different resolutions spanning the full page width. Below is how it looks in chrome including an image of when the page width expands

[image: Image on small screen]
[image: Image on larger screen]

The html for the SVG looks as follows

```
    <svg id="mobile-svg" data-name="Layer 2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 875.67 321.8" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <defs>
            <style>.cls-1{fill:#60b6e1;}</style>
        </defs>
        <clipPath id="myClip">
            <path d="M0,0S1,7.68,12.63,18.54,364.25,297.4,364.25,297.4s30.77,27.3,84.06.38,379.59-192,379.59-192S873.34,87.5,875.67,0H0Z" transform="translate(0)"></path>
         </clipPath>
         <image class="cls-image"  xlink:href="http://localhost:63342/Carfinance247Rebrand/Content/img/carDrivingImage.png" clip-path="url(#myClip)"/>
    </svg>
```

The CSS for the SVG (.SCSS)

```
  #mobile-svg {
      margin-bottom: -3px;
      background-color: #5fb6e0;
      .cls-image {
          width: 100%;
          height: 115%;
      }
  }
```

All works in chrome as expected but see image below for Firefox, the same thing also happens in IE (version 9 - 11)

[image: Firefox image]

I have tried changing position types and display types, also setting set width and ehights but cant get it to appear in other browsers.

I ahve an SVG that uses clip paths at a different point in the page and this one works fine, hence the confusion for this one. See image below of my working SVG

[image: workign example]

inb4 I am relatively new to SVG's

Comment: @Paulie_D clip-path is supported by IE for url clip paths on SVG elements

Comment: @Paulie_D I have a SVG with a clp path on IE at a different point in the page which works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In SVG 1.1 an `<image>` element must have height and width attributes i.e. you can't set the height and width via CSS.
- In SVG 2 it is proposed that image elements have width and height that are CSS properties.

Only Chrome has so far implemented this part of the SVG 2 specification.

Comment: i added the set width and height to the image and it is now appearing and scaling in other browsers but i have a quick question, in IE its stretching the image out of the normal shape whereas chrome and ff stays the same